# Django - what's the practice and most secure method of deleting or editing records for logged in users?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-forms, django-views

I have some sections on my web site where only logged in users can see their resources.

I also want to make absolutely sure that only that authorized user can modify and delete his/her records. What's the best practice and more secure way of accomplishing this in Django?

Real examples would be truly appreciated.

Comment: What more that "the user is logged in" and "deletion is forever, please confirm" would you want? If I want to delete stuff let me delete it. Please stop getting on my way.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that other users can't find a way to delete records that are not theirs. So I guess that's wall is needed? Just to check if user is logged in?

Comment: As long as there is no way another user could fake this login, that should be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my project, I created a [Decorator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators) that checked if the right user was logged in:

```
#decorator.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def same_user_required(func):
    def wrapper(request, user):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login-view'))
        if not user == request.user.username:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login-view'))
        return func(request, user)
    return wrapper
```

You then add it to any views that need checking:

```
#view_profile.py
from apps.utilities.decorators import same_user_required

@same_user_required
def edit_profile(request, user):
```

Note that my URL contains the username `/profile/edit/<username>`, which is where the parameter comes from, in the `edit_profile` view.

*Another* way is to use the Django built-in decorator, [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.user_passes_test) (see [Django Book Chap 14](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter14/) for an example of its usage. You then just have to write the test, not the decorator boilerplate code.

Comment: @itgorilla, you're welcome - also, please *note* that I changed the code indentation. I didn't properly re-indent it when cutting/pasting.